# Making VueJS data reactive to Node app output

Tags: node.js, vue.js, node-serialport

Is there a way to real-time sync (i.e. make reactive) some data from a VueJS application (developed using vue-cli) with the output of a node app (which returns a constantly changing JSON object)??

Node app accesses hardware resources (specifically the serial port, using [node-serialport](https://serialport.io/)) that are not accesible directly from the browser (VueJS frontend).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into Server/Client communication using websockets? You could have the browser be sent the node information whenever it is updated and then update Vue from there

Comment: Like @Snel23 said, look at Websockets and when you receive a message via Websockets, you best store it in a Vuex store where your whole application has access to it and you can create reactive getters etc. In node.js Socket.io is very popular.

Comment: Thanks to both. At last, I ended up packaging all of my VueJS app into an Electron-js app, which lets you just execute node code without browser restrictions, emulating a desktop app.